In react-bootstrap, align the link to the right of the screen
I'm currently creating a NavBar component in react, and here's what I have so far:
const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar className="bg-body-tertiary">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Home</Navbar.Brand>
      <Nav >
        <Nav.Link href="#About">About</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#Resume">Resume</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

Currently, I have the Home button aligned to the left of the screen, but so are the About and Resume tabs. How can I make it so that About and Resume are on the right?

You can add justify-content-between className to the outer NavBar, like this:
const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar className="bg-body-tertiary justify-content-between">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Home</Navbar.Brand>
      <Nav >
        <Nav.Link href="#About">About</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#Resume">Resume</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

You may want to read more about bootstrap's flex utilities in its webpage.

You can move the Nav element which includes the About and Resume links to the right of the Navbar by utilizing the ml-auto class. This class applies margin-left: auto, which pushes the Nav to the right:
import React from "react";
import { Navbar, Nav } from "react-bootstrap"; // import necessary components

const NavBar = () => {
  return (
    <Navbar className="bg-body-tertiary">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">Home</Navbar.Brand>
      <Nav className="ml-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#About">About</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#Resume">Resume</Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

export default NavBar;

Make sure that you're also importing the Bootstrap CSS in your project!
